# Euler project problem 58, where's the error

Tags: c

I'm just not able to see where's the error on my code, I am getting 26249 (or 26247 if I go back one spiral level), but it should be 26241.

Obviously, there must be a problem with my logic, but I can't point out where.

Spiral Primes, Project Euler Problem 58

Starting with 1 and spiralling anticlockwise in the following way, a square spiral with side length 7 is formed.

**37** 36 35 34 33 32 **31**
38 **17** 16 15 14 **13** 30
39 18  **05**  04  **03** 12 29
40 19  06 01 02 11 28
41 20  **07**  08  09 10 27
42 21 22 23 24 25 26
**43** 44 45 46 47 48 49

It is interesting to note that the odd squares lie along the bottom right diagonal, but what is more interesting is that 8 out of the 13 numbers lying along both diagonals are prime; that is, a ratio of 8/13 ≈ 62%.

If one complete new layer is wrapped around the spiral above, a square spiral with side length 9 will be formed. If this process is continued, what is the side length of the square spiral for which the ratio of primes along both diagonals first falls below 10%?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define print(ref) printf(#ref" = %d\n",ref);
#define printl(ref) printf(#ref" = %ld\n",ref);
#define NUM_OF_PRIMES 5000

int primesOnThisLevel(int);

void generatePrimes();
int isPrime(int);
int canBeExpressedAsPrime(int);

int primes[NUM_OF_PRIMES] = {2,3,5};
int primesFound = 3;

int main(){
    int numbersInDiagonal = 1;
    int primesInDiagonal = 0;
    int level;

    generatePrimes();

    for (level = 2 ; numbersInDiagonal/10 <= primesInDiagonal ; level++){
        primesInDiagonal += primesOnThisLevel(level);
        numbersInDiagonal += 4;
    }

    print(numbersInDiagonal)
    print(primesInDiagonal)
    int sideLenght = (2*level)-1;
    print(sideLenght*sideLenght);
    print(sideLenght);

    return 0;
}

int primesOnThisLevel(int level){
    int primesCount = 0;
    int sideLenght = (2*level)-1;
    int differenceBetweenCorners = 2*(level-1);
    int cornerValue = sideLenght*sideLenght;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        cornerValue -= differenceBetweenCorners;
        primesCount += isPrime(cornerValue);
    }
    return primesCount;
}

void generatePrimes(){
    for (int i = 7 ; primesFound < NUM_OF_PRIMES ; i +=2 ){
        if ( isPrime(i) ){
            primes[primesFound++] = i;
        }
    }
    print(primes[primesFound-1]);
}

int isPrime(int prospect){
    if ( prospect == 3 || prospect == 5 ) return 1;
    if ( !canBeExpressedAsPrime(prospect) ) return 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; primes[i]*primes[i] <= prospect ; i++)
        if ( prospect%primes[i] == 0 ) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int canBeExpressedAsPrime(int prospect){
    if ( prospect%6 == 1 ) return 1;
    if ( prospect%6 == 5 ) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Hi, it seems you are making more iterations than you need, even when the ratio is 10%. Indeed in you foor loop it goes on even if `numbersInDiagonal/10 <= primesInDiagonal`. Try to change your for loop with the following one to ensure that you stop when the ratio is exactly 10%: `for (level = 2 ; level < 3 || numbersInDiagonal < (primesInDiagonal*10); level++)`.

Comment: @Roberto, thank you very much It does indeed work, I guess I was tired, I do understand now, the extra two or three iterations were performed because they were at 10% then. 
I used ( numbersInDiagonal < (primesInDiagonal*10) || level < 3 ) instead, which in theory will be a tinsy bit more efficient. after all, we only need to check for the level once. would you mind answering so I can choose the answer?

Comment: I opted to use a do-while loop to avoid the level<3 check altogether, but you were right my condition was including the 10% boundary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special Thanks to Roberto Trani whom pointed out the error which was regarding boundaries, the previous limit included 10% which was not supposed to happen, here it is the ammended main function, which is the perfect situation to use a do-while loop.

```
int main(){
  int numbersInDiagonal = 1;
  int primesInDiagonal = 0;
  int level = 2;

  generatePrimes();

  do {
      primesInDiagonal += primesOnThisLevel(level);
      numbersInDiagonal += 4;
      level++;
  } while ( numbersInDiagonal < primesInDiagonal*10 );

  int sideLenght = (2*(--level))-1;
  print(sideLenght);

  return 0;
}
```